# How to create a MSSQL server connection in SOAPUI

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI. On internet i found, this can be done with two ways: Either i can use SoapUI JDBC wizard or Using groovy script.
First i tried to create connection using Wizard but i am getting this error :

> com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to init connection
>   for driver [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver],
>   connectionString
>   [jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://192.168.185.100\MyDB;databaseName=ABC?user=Test&password=Pass]

[image]
[image]

I extract the JDBC driver to path

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server

and Copy this Jar file

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL
>   Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar

to this folder

> C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\ext\sqljdbc4.jar

Added Environment Variable

> variable name : classpath
>
> variable value : C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL
>   Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;

Answer (score 1):

Add **sqljdbc_auth.dll**(use x64 or x32 based on your system configuration), to ***C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\ext*** (the same path where you have placed the sqljdbc4.jar file).

That seems to be the only step missing in the setup you have described. Once that is in place the JDBC test step request should work fine.

You can follow this thread on the SmartBear community for this particular issue.

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Solved-JDBC-Cannot-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-database/td-p/132235